# Access query to show repeated data as blank or as---"---

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have example data in MS ACCESS two parent and child table like, parent names and in child table Childs name, when I run query it shows repeated parent name, I want parent name to appear once only.

Appreciated if some can help me to build such MS ACCESS query.

I tried to apply GROUP BY function but it didn't work.
[image]

Comment: Excellent, it worked.... you are geniuses.... you are right, report is more efficient by using Grouping feature, but I need finally to copy to Excel sheet from Query, would you please advise how can I export data from report to Excel sheet. would be thankful....

Comment: Right click>Export or ribbon External Data or VBA TransferSpreadsheet. Report can be exported as well.

Comment: If answer resolves issue, please mark accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a correlated subquery that counts records in each child name group. This sort of SQL can perform slowly in Access. Other database platforms have native functions that can calculate a sequential value by group.

```
SELECT
    IIf((SELECT Count(*) AS Cnt FROM Children AS Dupe 
         WHERE Dupe.ParentID = Children.ParentID 
         AND Dupe.ChildID<Children.ChildID) > 0, "", ParentName) AS PN,
    ChildID, ChildName
FROM Children INNER JOIN Parents On Parents.ID = Children.ParentID
ORDER BY ParentID, ChildID;
```

Probably more efficient would be a report using its Sorting & Grouping features and/or textbox HideDuplicates property.